# BTEQ The activity count returned by DBS does not match the actual number of rows returned

Tags: teradata

When I am exporting a table from teradata using BTEQ, the output row count does not match the select query count. The following is the warning shown by BTEQ

```
Warning: The activity count returned by DBS does not match
              the actual number of rows returned.
              Activity Count=495294, Total Rows Returned=495286
```

Here is the select query,

```
SELECT CUST_ID, SPEC1_CODE FROM Table
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Here is the create table script,

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE Table ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
     (
      RECORD_KEY DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL,
      CUST_ID VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      SPEC1_CODE VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( RECORD_KEY );
```

When we contacted Teradata support, they asked us to run the following query.

```
DIAGNOSTIC NOAGGRENH ON FOR SESSION;
```

So, if we run the above query and then run our select/BTEQ export, it is working fine.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the SELECT statement that generated the warning message? Is the source table defined as SET or MULTISET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping you would answer my questions in the comment sooner but I'm going to throw this out as a possible reason for the discrepancy you are seeing in the warning message.

Your table is defined as MULTISET with a non-unique primary index or possibly as a NOPI table in Teradata 13.x. There are no additional unique constraints on the table or unique indexes. The table has been loaded with 8 duplicate rows of data.

For reasons that I can not pinpoint based on your description BTEQ returned a unique set of records although the optimizer indicates that the activity count for the statement was greater. Thus the warning message that you are seeing.

Comment: The GROUP BY definitely shouldn't have resulted in that warning message being displayed. Not familiar with that particular diagnostic. I wonder if this relates to an open NTA for which the DR is not available or has not been applied to your environment.